# How to create generic class for WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have service now wfc services in my application each service has different base class

```
public partial class ServiceNowSoapClient : SNtoVSTSIntegration.SNInterfaceIncident.ServiceNowSoap
public partial class ServiceNowSoapClient : SNInterfaceAttachmentMetadata.ServiceNowSoap
```

The problem is that there's no simple base class for a WCF Web Service
how to create generic class which return me object of ServiceNowSoapClient
Is ther any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Different service base addresses correspond to different service endpoint addresses. We must specify the service endpoint address when instantiating the client proxy, so there is no way to implement a generic class for all service proxy classes.
Besides, Channel Factory also can encapsulate the creation of a client proxy.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.